# Bullet hit, calculate pressure

Tags: classical-mechanics

I wanna calculate the stress that is there when a bullet hits a metall plate.
i know the formula pressure = force / area
But how can I calculate the force?

Comment: A bullet with some mass and velocity is stopped over some distance (the length of the bullet is a good first approximation).